# MySql LIKE returns false if search term is same as entire string in the column, why is that?

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

So I have following as part of my query

`SELECT * FROM $table WHERE columname  LIKE '%$searchterm%'`

I have tried taking out leading and/or ending wildcards meaning

`SELECT * FROM $table WHERE columname  LIKE '$searchterm%'`

AND

`SELECT * FROM $table WHERE columname  LIKE '%$searchterm'`

AND

`SELECT * FROM $table WHERE columname  LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR columname LIKE '$searchterm'`

and also tried adding following to the query with no luck

`OR columname = '$searchterm'`

So when my search term is "myval" and if column has whole string "myval", I would like to have that selected. But ALL of my queries above, return false/return nothing where myval is searchterm and column value as full.

I can not use `MATCH` because this is not Full-Text index.

**EDIT:**

PHP Code:

```
    $sterm = NULL;
            $table = 'mytable';

    if(isset($_GET['s'])) {     $sterm = explode(" ", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['s']));    }

    if(isset($_POST['s'])) {    $sterm = explode(" ", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s']));   }

    if(!empty($sterm)){
        $getdata = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE termsi != 'Special' "; 

        foreach ($sterm as $value){

            $getdata .= "AND netid_all  LIKE '%$value%' OR  netid_all  = '$value' ";                
        } //End foreach

        $getdata .= "LIMIT 10";

        $result = mysql_query($getdata) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo <<<PRINTALL
            {$row[0]}, {$row[1]}, {$row[2]}, {$row[3]}, {$row[4]}, {$row[5]}, {$row[6]}, {$row[7]}, ' <br />'               
PRINTALL;
        } //End While
    } //End If search exists
```

Okay So As you guys suggested, i tried PHPMyAdmin sql console and it works fine, so it would have to be by PHP!? so here it is.

Comment: Are you sure `$searchterm` contains that value, because it doesn't seem like that to me? Try running the query with a test string in the command line or phpMyAdmin, whichever you have access to.

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, but have you tried using = instead of LIKE?

Comment: @Pelshoff: Seems like he has tried it and still getting nothing...

Comment: Yea, but with the wildcards :)

Comment: @Shef: I did add echo so the value is passed on correctly and the table column does have that value. So instead of myval, if i were to search with myva it would work and if i do val it would work but it only breaks when entire strings are same, so i was wondering if it has anything to do with wildcards, meaning do wildcards mean at least something before or after in place of wildcard has to be there?

Comment: @Pelshoff: You can have wildcards for "=" ? I thought it would be escaped meaning it would search for character "%" as part of the string. Well can't hurt to try, so i will.

Comment: I don't think you can, but I've never had this problem with wildcards, so just try stuff

Comment: @Tumharyyaaden: If the string matches a full value, the wild cards will not have an effect on the query, unless you add something else before or after the wild card. If you did try the query on a command line or phpMyAdmin, and it works, then you should share the PHP code, maybe you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: I agree with Shef. Just tried it on the [pma demo site](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/?pma_username=root), "%hello%" also finds "hello"!

Comment: @Pelshoff: could you please check the que again? I added my php to it...And yes, in my pma, all the queries work as expected, so would you look at my PHP and tell me whats going on? Thanks

Comment: @cularis: please check edited que again.

Comment: @Shef: please check edited que again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well found it,

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Was the problem, earlier when I was testing things, anyhow, it should have been the following

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    while($row)
```

Comment: After making @MarcB working hard on your question, I can understand no selection as an answer but no upvote? That's not cool man

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing your query building like this:

```
$fullvalues = array();
$partials = array();
foreach ($sterm as $value){
   $partials[] = "(netid_all LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "%')";
   $fullvalues[] = "'" .  mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}
$partials = implode(' OR ', $partials);
$fullvalues = implode(', ', $fullvalues);

$sql = <<<EOL
SELECT *
FROM $table
WHERE (termsi != 'Special')
   AND (($partials) OR (netid_all IN ($fullvalues));
EOL;
```

Assuming your search string is `a b c`, you'd get this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE (termsi != 'Special')
   AND (((netid_all LIKE '%a%') OR (netid_all LIKE '%b%') OR (netid_all LIKE '%C%')) OR (netid_all IN ('a', 'b', 'c')))
```

If your search requires that all terms be present, then change the 'OR' to 'AND' in the implode.

Comment: Could you explain the (netid_all IN ('a', 'b', 'c')) part?

Comment: It's treated the same as `(netid_all = 'a') or (netid_all = 'b') or (netid_all = 'c'))`. It's just a nicer/terser method of writing that out.

Comment: So if i am searching multiple columns, could i do `AND (($partials) OR (netid_all IN ($fullvalues)) OR (($partials) OR (second_column IN ($fullvalues));` ?

Comment: as long as you get the bracketing correct, yeah. stepping back a layer and going bird's eye view: `WHERE ... (field1 stuff) or (field2 stuff) or (field3 stuff) etc...`. At some point though, it'd get complex enough that you SHOULD switch to fulltext or use an external search engine like Lucene if fulltext isn't possible.

Comment: Is this most optimum way to run the query without fulltext? I only have read access to the server and database so I am not able to change anything or install search engines. But since the two tables i am running queries on are now 69k+ each, i would like to know if this is best possible way. or was the way i was doing it better in terms of performance?

Comment: Also, what was the problem with my script? I would like to know my mistakes...if you have the time, if you don't, thanks anyways

Comment: I wouldn't call it optimum, but it's about the only practical way to simulate a full-text index. Efficiency will defnitely be crappy as the number of search terms go up. As for your script, I'm thinking it might have been the way mysql was seeing all the repeated and/or clauses and wasn't filtering the way you wanted.